# Unable to play GIF image in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, animated-gif

I am trying to play the GIF images with the Xamarin.Forms (Portable) project. I have implemented with the following code but unable to Play GIF, I don't event see the static image.

> There is no error or crash in this code, but I am not able to see the
>   GIF image.

Is there anything wrong in the code?

Interface:

```
public interface IGif
{
   string Get();
}
```

iOS Implementation:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GifView_iOS))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
 public class GifView_iOS : IGif
 {
   public string Get()
   {
     return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
   }
 }
}
```

Android Implementation:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GifView_Droid))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
 public class GifView_Droid : IGif
 {
   public string Get()
   {
     return "file:///android_asset/";
   }
 }
}
```

GIF Image class:

```
public class Gif: WebView
{
    public string GifSource
    {
    set
    {
        string imgSource = DependencyService.Get<IGif>.Get() + value; 
        var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        html.Html = String.Format
            (@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>",
             imgSource);
        SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
    }
  }
}
```

And Finally, I have added to the StackLayout.

```
Gif gifimage = new Gif();
gifimage.GifSource = "loading.gif";
StackGif.Children.Add(gifimage);
```

> I have not tested this code in iPhone, maybe it is working in iPhone.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What is happening? Does it crash? Doesn't it show anything? Do you get an error message? Stacktrace? Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually, there are not issue or crash, but I am not able to see the `GIF` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the silly mistake, I have to give the size of Image inside web view and to GIF class also.

Here is the updated code.

My GIF Class:

```
public class Gif: WebView
{
    public string GifSource
    {
        set
        {
            string imgSource = DependencyService.Get<Dependency.IGif>().Get() + value;
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            html.Html = String.Format(@"<html><body><img src='{0}'  style='width: 100px; height: 100px;' /></body></html>", imgSource);
            SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
        }
    }
}
```

and Initialization in ContentPage:

```
Helpers.Controls.Gif gifImage = new Helpers.Controls.Gif();
gifImage.GifSource = "loading.gif";
gifImage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
gifImage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
gifImage.HeightRequest = 120;
gifImage.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
GridLoad.Children.Add(gifImage);
```

> Note: I am still working on the Background Part, as it is looking like
>   attached image, I want the transparent background in web view.

Image:[image]

Comment: You cannot make WebView background transparent without custom renderers

Comment: It is enough to give the size request. You don't have to set image size inside your html

Answer (score 0):

By default StackLayout occupies the whole available space but WebView doesn't.
Instead just

```
Gif gifimage = new Gif();
```

use

```
public WebViewProgrammaticallyPage()
        {
            var StackGif = new StackLayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor=Color.Red,
            };
            Gif gifimage = new Gif()
            {
                WidthRequest = 120,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 80,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            gifimage.GifSource = "icon1.png";
            StackGif.Children.Add(gifimage);

            Content = StackGif;
        }
```

[image]

Transparency of WebView is different problem. You should use custom renderers
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34957/creating-a-webview-with-a-transparent-background

Comment: let me give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: no. It doesn't work. I have tried to add a test in HTML but still, doesn't work from me. `<html><body style='background: #000000;'>hello<img src='{0}' /></body></html>`

Comment: actually, I have tried this code and that also not working for me, there are something that I am missing. `https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#HTML_Strings`

Comment: What exactly is not working? Make sure your file is in asset folder and build action is AndroidAsset