# Transparent background of WebView in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I am able to play GIF image in Xamarin.Forms (Portable) but now I need to remove the background of the WebView. So, that it will look pretty good.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096696/4025613) is the link for the GIF player in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Comment: Why do you need WebView? Can't you use Image? If you need more "things" you can use Layouts

Comment: @YuriS The Image control doesn't support animated GIF's so that's not an option either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yuri S already mentioned, you shouldn't be using the WebView. It's an overkill for such a simple task as showing a GIF animation. 
Instead, you should look at the [GifImageView](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Awesome-Controls/tree/master/GifImageView) control by James Montenegro. It extends the default Image control with GIF capabilities using custom renderers for iOS and Android.

If you really want to use the WebView, you need to write your own custom renderer for each platform to achieve true transparency.

**iOS:** Set the `Opaque` property to false and make sure that the background color is UIColor.Clear. The default implementation of Xamarin.Forms WebView already has the background color set, so you only need to take care of the Opaque property.

**Android:** Set the `BackgroundColor`property of the WebView to `0x00000000`

**PCL:** Make sure that the body of your HTML page has a transparent background. Otherwise it will be white and the transparency setting of your underlying WebView doesn't matter. `<body style="background-color: transparent;">`

Comment: It's not compulsory to use the WebView control, but I was not aware of the GifImageView control. I will check this now. Thank You.

Comment: I can't add `GifImageView` from NuGet packages. is there any other way to use it?

Comment: The iOS section of your answer was very helpful for applying transparent background to a custom renderer of Editor view.